# Perform a Thiel-Sen regression on a raster stack in R

Tags: raster, r, ndvi, regression

I have a raster stack of 20 layers. Each layer represent accumulated NDVI values for the growing season for each year spanning my period of study.
I want to perform a trend analysis using Thiel-Sen estimator.
Fitting a traditional OLS linear model works using this code:

```
NDVI <- stack("NDVI.tif")
fun <- function(x){if(is.na(x[1])){NA}else{m=lm(x ~ time); summary(m)$coefficients[2]}}
slope_raster <- calc(NDVI, fun)
```

I am trying to fit a Thiel-Sen estimator from the **'mblm'** package by modifying the above function with

```
fun <- function(x){if(is.na(x[1])){NA}else{m=mblm(x ~ time); summary(m)$coefficients[2]}}
```

and I get the following error:

```
Error in order(x) : argument 1 is not a vector
In addition: Warning message:
In .Internal(gc(verbose, reset, full))
```

What could be the problem here?

Comment: I'm struggling to see any difference between those two `fun` definitions (and they both work for me) - have you left something out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I'll make a sample stack with 20 layers of 3x4 cells:

```
> rs = lapply(1:20, function(i){raster(matrix(runif(12),3,4))})
> NDVI = do.call(stack, rs)
> time = 1:20
```

Next lets see if that reproduces your error. I've used the `mblm` function in the place of `lm` in your code, which I think is what you meant to do:

```
> fun <- function(x){if(is.na(x[1])){NA}else{m=mblm(x~time); summary(m)$coefficients[2]}}
> slope_raster <- calc(NDVI, fun)
Error in .calcTest(x[1:5], fun, na.rm, forcefun, forceapply) : 
  cannot use this function
```

okay good, same error. You should always try and include sample code/data to fully reproduce the error to save work for anyone answering.

How modelling functions resolve the names in formulae (like `x~time`) is always a bit ropey, so I tried putting the values into a data frame inside the function, and modelling on that:

```
> fun <- function(x){
   if(is.na(x[1])){
     NA
   }else{
     D=data.frame(X=time,Y=x)
     m=mblm(Y~X,data=D)
     summary(m)$coefficients[2]
   }
  }
> slope_raster <- calc(NDVI, fun)
There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
>
```

That does seem to work. So its some quirk of how `mblm` is evaluating its formula. I think the warnings are possibly because I have a small data set here, or something else wrong. If your data doesn't produce them, then great, if it does then some investigation is needed...

Comment: This worked like a charm. Thank you for the time and sorry for the typo in my question where I typed "lm" instead "mblm".